# Open files (io.open json or display.newImage) from DocumentsDirectory subfolder with Corona SDK build for Android

Tags: android, coronasdk, subdirectory, documentsdirectory

I'm building a lua application with Corona SDK.

On Android device, I'm finding not possible to open files (such us json files) from DocumentsDirectory subdirectories after successfully downloaded with network.download. However that does work in Corona Simulator!

So no success with Android device. On the device, just the files downloaded at DocumentsDirectory root can be opened with no problems, but not the ones placed in subdirectories. As I say, Corona Simulator does work well.

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't understand why that would be happening.  Do you have your phone plugged into your computer and do you run `ADB logcat`? Possibly your phone doesn't load the files fast enough and it times out and gives you an error.  You might also want to check to see if your phone supports downloading that kind of file.